# How to create a random Unicode or UTF-8 file in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem with the encoding of my files. These are direct access files. The TextBoxes that feed these files are able to display all characters, in Polish, Ukrainian, etc. and of course in my language, in French, with all the accented characters.

On the other hand, thinking that they have to be encoded in Unicode, while they are created in utf8, well I think (I'm not sure at all), after saving the data, the exotic accents disappear ! Only the French accents remain!

Example : `Róża Czacka`. Which gives me `Róza Czacka` once recorded!

The code I use to save my files:

```
Nbr = FreeFile()

FileOpen(Nbr, OuvrirFichier, OpenMode.Random, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, _
         OpenShare.LockWrite, Len(bibliotheque))

enreg = FileLen(OuvrirFichier) \ Len(bibliotheque) 

With bibliotheque
    .Title = TextBox2.Text
    .Name = TextBox1.Text
    .Charge = TextBox4.Text
    .Institute = TextBox15.Text
    .Celebration = TextBox5.Text
    .Birth = TextBox7.Text
    .Death = TextBox9.Text
    .Otherparties = TextBox13.Text
    .Othernames = TextBox18.Text
    .Venerable = TextBox23.Text
    .Beatified = TextBox24.Text
    .Canonized = TextBox25.Text
    .Heading = TextBox26.Text
    .Patron = TextBox28.Text
    .Link = TextBox29.Text
    .Biography = TextBox31.Text
    .Image = TextBox33.Text
End With

FilePut(Nbr, bibliotheque, enreg)
FileClose(Nbr)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you post the code you used to save those text files? The default encoding is UTF-8 in many of the standard methods. Or did you specify Encoding.Dafault?

Comment: No, I didn't specify Encoding Default.

Comment: This is not VB.Net, this is VB6. If you actually want to write VB.Net code, see the [System.IO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io) namespace. Take a look at the File, FileStream and StreamReader / StreamWriter classes.

Comment: If this is fine under vb.Net, I should have used another method!

Comment: I have a problem with the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FilePut Method! In fact, I don't really know which end to start with!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. None of the methods worked correctly, so I was still left with ANSI encoded files when I wanted the character display to be UTF-8 encoded!

Under Windows 10 (among others), open the control panel> Region> the Administration tab> Change regional settings ...> then, check the box: Beta as shown in the screenshot below. That's all.

[image]

Claude

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the functions you're calling are so dated that many people will not recognize them. In fact, I had to look up a few of them myself in order to understand what you were doing. It is recommended to use the methods in the [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem) class. If you need more flexibility, you can look at the classes in the [`System.IO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io).

In your case, you appear to be trying to save a binary object into a file and for that you can use the [`BinaryFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter). Here is a sample code slightly modified from what is provided on the Microsoft Docs page for the [BinaryFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter) class.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim bibliotheque = New With {
            .Title = "Title",
            .Name = "NameOf",
            .Charge = "Charge" ' add other initialization code
        }

        Using fs = New FileStream("C:\folder\file.dat", FileMode.Create)
            Dim bf = New BinaryFormatter()
            bf.Serialize(fs, bibliotheque)
        End Using
    End Sub

End Module
```

You can also look at the same page for the BinaryFormatter for a sample on how to deserialize (or open) the saved object.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex Essilfie. What does deserialize mean? It seems to me that deserialize (or deserialization) means to record. Is this it, and conversely, serialize would mean to open or create a bianire file?

Comment: The created file is originally in UTF-8, but as soon as I write inside it reverts to ANSI?